# Is it safe to pass memory allocated using "new" to C libraries?

Tags: c++, c, memory, libraries

I know that `new` `delete` are incombatible with `malloc` `free`.

Does that mean that I should avoid using `new` for memory that will be used by a C library?

What are things that can go wrong when using `new` instead of `malloc` when I will pass the memory to a C library?

```
void func()
{
    int *p = new int(42);

    // Should I insist on using malloc for p if this function is a part
    // of a C library?
    lib_func(p);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Memory is memory, and it does not matter how it was allocated.

As long as you're matching `new` with `delete`, `new[]` with `delete[]` and `malloc`/`calloc` with `free` (also `realloc`), you're okay.

If you think about it, even C allocates memory in different places, and it works fine --- if a library expects an `int`, you can allocate it either on the stack, or on the heap (or in some global storage):

```
int a;
int* b = malloc(sizeof(int));
static int c;

some_func(&a);
some_func(b);
some_func(&c);
```

Comment: @pm100 it's perfectly well-defined. All what's required by the standards is what's written here. On Stack Overflow, we don't provide "of course it just works" answers. Asserting that is actually very rude.

Comment: so some part of the c++ standard say the the result of new is identical to the result of malloc (apart from the constructor invokation side-effect)

Comment: @pm100: In a way, yes. It's in the same memory space (as proven by the fact that both `new` and `malloc` can create pointers of type `T*`).

Answer (score 7):

> Does that mean that I should avoid using new for memory that will be used by a C library?

Not at all. The memory is the same, so if you provide a safe way to deallocate the memory, you can definitely pass that memory to a C library.

```
int *p = new int(42);
lib_func(p);
delete p;
```

Here is another example:

```
extern "C" {
    int* make_buffer(size_t sz) {
        return new int[sz];
    }
    void use_buffer(int* buf) {
        ... // do something
    }
    void free_buffer(int* buf) {
        delete[] buf;
    }
}
```

The code above lets your C code request dynamically allocated memory from your C++ library.

Answer (score 4):

It is memory as any other so it is safe as long as the C library does not `free` it.

Note that in your example, you can also use memory on stack which has no allocation or deallocation functions:

```
void func()
{
    int p;
    lib_func(&p);
}
```